# mongoose findOne method is returning null

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, mongoose, graphql

I am following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G2vt7BW4Sgw&t=1163s&list=PLzQWIQOqeUSM51q7ZIqvDQ-Myp58IVPEN&index=8) tutorial. Even though code is exactly what is mentioned in the tutorial, every time i run the graphql mutation query to update a particular tweet, it returns `null` and logs `null` on cmd.

I verified mongoose version is same (4.11.3).I believe something is wrong with findOne method as even in deleteTweet resolver, findOne is returning `null`. Is it because findOne needs a callback? but in the tutorial there is no callback passed. I also noticed that findOneAndUpdate works fine but it creates a new entry rather updating the existing tweet.

```
  updateTweet: async (_, { id, ...rest}, { user }) => {
    try {
      await requireAuth(user)
      const tweet = await Tweet.findOne({ id, user: user.id });
      console.log(tweet);

      if(!tweet) {
        throw new Error('Not Found!');
      }

      return tweet.save();

    } catch (e) {
      throw e;
    }
  },


  deleteTweet: async (_, { id }, { user }) => {
    try {
      await requireAuth(user);
      const tweet = await Tweet.findOne({ id, user: user.id });

      if(!tweet) {
        throw new Error('Not Found !')
      }

      await tweet.remove();
      return {
        message: "Deleted Tweet Successfully"
      }
    }catch(error) {
      throw error;
    }
  }
}
```

**TweetSchema**

```
import mongoose, { Schema } from 'mongoose';

const TweetSchema = new Schema({
  text: {
   type: String,
   minlength: [5, 'Text need to be longer'],
   maxlength: [144, 'Text is too long'],
 },
  user: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
  },
  favoriteCount: {
    type: Number,
    default: 0
  }
}, { timestamps: true})

export default mongoose.model('Tweet', TweetSchema);
```

Comment: What is `id`? What is its value?

Comment: Id is generated by graphql and stored in tweet collection on mongodb

This is what it logs after running the update query on graphiql
tweets.findOne({ user: ObjectId("5bcbcac57870760db4ff34ab"), id: '5bcbcac57870760db4ff34ab'}, {fields: {} })null

Comment: so your id needs to be `ObjectId(id)`

Comment: `Tweet.findOne({ id: mongo.ObjectID(id), user: user.id })`

Comment: But TweetSchema already has it, could you please check the edit.

Comment: TweetSchema only has `user` but not `id`.

Comment: @Akrion I installed mongodb module and imported it but it is still not working.

Comment: @ZeroCho Could you please suggest what i need to do then to make it work ?

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo. In MongoDB, the key field is **_id** NOT id. This is added automatically by MongoDB unless provided, so you need to change your code to use _id instead.

Comment: No i am sure problem is not with _id as i have a getTweet resolver like this getTweet: async (_, { id }, { user }) => {
    try {
      await requireAuth(user);
      return Tweet.findById(id);
    } catch (e) {
      throw e;
    }
  }and it gives the result fine, and i  already tried _id  too but it didn't work.

Comment: findById doesn't take an object, it takes the actual value. So when you do findById(id) it's different to findOne({ id }), as the latter will incorrectly use the key name id

Comment: If you change the code in updateTweet to: 

const tweet = await Tweet.findOne({ _id: id, user: user.id }); // it may also need to be user._id if that's a db object.

Does that work?

Comment: thanks for the info ! i know that key field is _id but when i was setting up initially with _id it was giving me some error " "ID cannot represent value: { _bsontype: \"ObjectID\"" that's why i changed the _id to id everywhere, does it make difference ?

Comment: Just now i changed all the id to _id to try and it still giving me the same error while running any query.

Comment: Yes, it makes a difference. MongoDB by default uses _id, so it adds this automatically to all documents if not provided; so you need to use this in queries if you want to find anything. You can add a field named id if you want, but you haven't got that in your schema so I'm assuming you're searching on _id. 

I'd have to see the code that causes the bsonType error, but I'd suspect you were trying to do something with it without calling toString()

Comment: Can you upload sample code to github? and I'll take a look